# apply last-event with any-key not working as expected

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I have an editor which is linked to a database field. 
When the user pushes certain keys the program should behave differently, 
for the rest of keys it should maintain the default behaviour. I am using this part of code:

```
ON ANY-KEY OF editor_1 IN FRAME F-Main
DO:
   APPLY LAST-EVENT:LABEL TO SELF.
   RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.
```

The problem is that when APPLY LAST-EVENT:LABEL is executed the editor does not behave as default.

Some examples of the behaviour by default, i.e. when any-key is not triggered:

- CTRL+C is used for copying selected text
- CTRL+V is used for pasting the copyed text

After triggering any-key in the editor, the program works like this:

- CTRL+C aplication ABORTS
- CTRL+V does not work
- CURSORS DOWN/RIGHT/LEFT/UP do not work
- BACKSPACE does not work

Is there anyway of triggering any-key without overwritting the default behaviour?

Note: Progress 4GL is v11.3 and is executed from windows.

Comment: What are the special events? I can reproduce what you're saying, and I noticed coding for ctrl-c ctrl-v accordingly will restore the function. But it's probably easier just code for the special events you're trying to capture.

Answer (score 1):

You should map the key labels to the key FUNCTION that you want to apply.

Something like:

```
ON ANY-KEY OF editor_1 IN FRAME F-Main
DO:
   if last-event:label = "backspace" then
     apply delete-char to self.
    else
     apply lastkey to self.
   /* use a CASE statement to extend this... */
   RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it's cumbersome to manage some of the events. For example, I haven't found any good and clean solution for the cursor to move-up and down within the editor. Plus, there are many events, and I'm not sure if I am forgetting any. I will try to trigger special keys, and let's see. The complex thing is that the special keys are stored in a table, and I would need to dynamically create the triggers, plus some of the special keys are a combination of different special keys. This is easier to manage with any-key except for the default events. Thanks.

Comment: Just one litle thing about your code, it didn't work for me as it is and I modified it to  editor:DELETE-CHAR ()

Answer (score 1):

I talked to progress and there is no solution for this issue. This issue with ANY-KEY is related to editors.

You could map some key labels to specific key FUNCTION, but there are certain events where it is not possible (for example, cursor movements).

At the end I had to trigger for special keys, but in this particular case it was preferable something like ANY-KEY.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering an event on any key, why not just do it for those special keys?

For example, the control-C behavior would be in this trigger:

```
ON CTRL-C of editor_1 IN FRAME F-Main
```